# Repetition in values of sequences of type $s_{n+1} = s_n + n^x / 10^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume we have a sequence of type $a_n=\frac{n^x}{10^n}$.The corresponding series would be one with the formula $s_{n+1}=s_n+\frac{n^x}{10^n}$.

We can obviously see that when x = 1, this would result in $s_n$ approaching the value 0.123456... And indeed, when I checked using Python, I got the following output: `0.1234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567901234567898`

This matches the idea that there should be a repeating pattern. However, when instead using x = 2 or 3, I also get a repitition. These are my outputs: `0.1508916323731138545953360768175582990397805212620027434842249657064471879286694101508916323731138545953360768175582990397805212620027434842249657064471879286694101508916323731138545953360768175582990397805212620027434842249657064471879286694101508916323731138545953360768175582990397804271` (repitition always starts with 1508) and `0.2149062642889803383630544124371284865112025605852766346593507087334247828074988568815729309556470050297210791037951531778692272519433013260173754000914494741655235482395976223136716963877457704618198445358939186099679926840420667581161408321902149062642889803383630544124371284865111751489` (with the repitition always starting with 2149)

Where does this pattern stem from?

My code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/8QNgWWxh).

Comment: This simply is a consequence of the fact that $s_n$ converges to a rational number. Do you know some theory of geometric series?

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. I have heard of geometric series a while ago and I guess we're gonna cover it in class soon. Could you write an answer including which number that'd be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the standard geometric series (defined over real numbers $y$ such that $|y|<1$):
$$f(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} y^n= \frac{1}{1-y}$$
And compute the first derivative of $f$:
$$f'(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} ny^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-y)^2} $$
so that
$$yf'(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} ny^n = \frac{y}{(1-y)^2}$$
Now plug $y= 1/10$ to get
$$\frac{1}{10} + \frac{2}{10^2} + \frac{3}{10^3} + \frac{4}{10^4} +  \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} n(1/10)^n = \frac{(1/10)}{(1-(1/10))^2}= \frac{10}{81}$$
whose decimal expansion is indeed $0.123456790123...$

To compute the values of the other series you need to involve derivatives of higher order, but in general you will get always rational functions. Plugging a rational number (i.e. $y=1/10$) will always give you a rational number (thus periodic decimal) as a result.

Answer (score 2):

For $x\in \{0,1,2,...\}$, let$$
b_x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x}{10^n} = \frac{1^x}{10^1} + \frac{2^x}{10^2} + \frac{3^x}{10^3} +\cdots
$$
so $b_x$ is the limit of your sequence. Observe $b_0 = 0.1111...=\frac{1}{9}$. We will show that $b_x$ is always rational for non-negative integers $x$. Suppose $x\ge 1$: 
\begin{eqnarray}
b_{x} &=& \frac{1^x}{10^1} + \frac{2^x}{10^2} + \frac{3^x}{10^3} +\cdots \\
&=& \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{(1+1)^{x}}{10^1} + \frac{(1+2)^x}{10^2} + \frac{(1+3)^x}{10^3}+\cdots\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Expanding out each term using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), we obtain 
\begin{eqnarray}
b_x &=& \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{(1+1)^{x}}{10^1} + \frac{(1+2)^x}{10^2} + \frac{(1+3)^x}{10^3}+\cdots\right)\\
&=& \frac1{10} + \frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{\binom{x}{0}1^0 + \binom{x}{1}1^1 + \cdots + \binom{x}{x}1^x }{10^1} + \frac{\binom{x}{0}2^0 + \binom{x}{1}2^1 + \cdots + \binom{x}{x}2^x }{10^1}  +\cdots\right)
\end{eqnarray}
grouping like terms together, we get \begin{eqnarray}
b_x &=& \frac1{10} + \frac{1}{10}\left(\binom{x}{0}\left(\frac{1^0}{10^1} + \frac{2^0}{10^2} + \frac{3^0}{10^3} +\cdots\right) + \binom{x}{1}\left(\frac{1^1}{10^1} + \frac{2^1}{10^2} + \frac{3^1}{10^3} +\cdots\right) + \cdots\\
\cdots+ \binom{x}{x-1}\left(\frac{1^{x-1}}{10^1} + \frac{2^{x-1}}{10^2} + \frac{3^{x-1}}{10^3} +\cdots\right) + \binom{x}{x}\left(\frac{1^x}{10^1} + \frac{2^x}{10^2} + \frac{3^x}{10^3} +\cdots\right)\right) \\
&=&\frac1{10} + \frac{1}{10}\left(\binom{x}{0}b_0 + \binom{x}{1}b_1 + \cdots \binom{x}{x-1}b_{x-1} + \binom{x}{x}b_x\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Using the fact that $\binom{x}{x} = 1$, we can solve this equation for $b_x$ and obtain the recurrence relation $$
b_x = \frac19 + \frac19 \binom{x}{0}b_0 + \frac19\binom{x}{1}b_1 + \cdots + \frac19\binom{x}{x-1}b_{x-1}
$$
Clearly, we will always get a rational number since each term is just a sum of rational numbers that we got previously in the sequence.

Computation of the first few terms:\begin{eqnarray}
b_0 &=& \frac19\\
b_1 &=& \frac19 + \frac{1}9\binom{1}{0}b_0 = \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{9} = \frac{10}{81} = 0.12345678901234...\\
b_2 &=& \frac19 + \frac19\binom{2}{0}b_0 + \frac19\binom{2}{1}b_1 = \frac19+\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac19 + 2\cdot\frac19\cdot\frac{10}{81} = \frac{110}{729} \approx 0.15089...\\
b_3 &=& \frac19 + \frac{1}{9}\binom{3}{0}b_0 + \frac{1}{9}\binom{3}{1}b_1 + \frac{1}{9}\binom{3}{2}b_2 = \frac{470}{2187} \approx 0.21490...\\
b_4 &=&\frac19 + \frac{1}{9}\binom{4}{0}b_0 + \frac{1}{9}\binom{4}{1}b_1 + \frac{1}{9}\binom{4}{2}b_2 +\frac{1}{9}\binom{4}{3}b_3= \frac{7370}{19683} \approx 0.37443...\\
\vdots
\end{eqnarray}

More generally, $f(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^x}{y^n}$ is always rational for nonnegative integers $x$ and rational numbers $y$. This is a special case of the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) with a negative index; $f(x,y) = \mathrm{Li}_{-x}(1/y)$. For $x\in\{0,1,2,...\}$, this is a rational function of $y$ (see Crostul's answer).